# Generate elevation data from relief source

Tags: qgis, global-mapper

Can I use relief source to generate an elevation data or even edit/ merge with another elevation data?
Not referenced from real world.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean creating a DEM from a hillshade?

Comment: I'm still new to GIS work. what I have is some line shape files with height value in them. I want to use them to generate elevation data. If I understand your question. That would be yes.

Comment: Search for DEM from contours - there's lot of info already for this task